# Scroll to top of RecyclerView using setOnClickListener

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have this home button in top bar:

```
val activity: ImageButton =findViewById(R.id.activity)
        activity.setOnClickListener{
            startActivity(Intent(this, ActivitySearch::class.java))
        }
```

Instead of going to a new page, I want to be able to just put a "to top" intent, I have tried to replace:

```
startActivity(Intent(this, ActivitySearch::class.java))
```

with

```
mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

But this does not work, any ideas? I do have a RecyclerView in use so half way down, I want to be able to click the above button and it goes straight to the top.

Total code:

```
    private val apiService by lazy {
        ApiClient.create()
    }


    private var taskData : ArrayList<TaskResponse> = arrayListOf();

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val activity: ImageButton =findViewById(R.id.activity)
        activity.setOnClickListener{
            startActivity(Intent(this, ActivitySearch::class.java))
        }

        val searchbutton:ImageButton=findViewById(R.id.searchbutton)
        searchbutton.setOnClickListener{
            startActivity(Intent(this, ActivitySearch::class.java))
        }

        val saves:ImageButton=findViewById(R.id.saves)
        saves.setOnClickListener{
            startActivity(Intent(this, ActivitySaves::class.java))
        }

        val settings:ImageButton=findViewById(R.id.settings)
        settings.setOnClickListener{
            startActivity(Intent(this, ActivitySettings::class.java))
        }
        loadData();

    }

    private fun loadData(){
        var data = apiService.getMainData();

        data.enqueue(object : Callback<ArrayList<TaskResponse>> {

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<ArrayList<TaskResponse>>,
                response: Response<ArrayList<TaskResponse>>
            ) {

                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    taskData = response.body()!!;
                    displaydata();
                }

            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ArrayList<TaskResponse>>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("-----------------", t.toString())
            }
        })


    }

    private fun displaydata(){
        var recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.mainList);
        var adapter = TaskAdapter(this, taskData);
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter



        val swipeRefreshLayout: SwipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout)
// load data on swipe refresh.
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener { loadData() }
// Disable the refreshing after data load
        swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false


    }
```

And what i'm using for activity page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.1dp"
            android:background="#6A6A6A"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchbutton"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.01" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/w2d"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.047"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.01" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/activity"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:contentDescription="@string/activities"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:tint="#00B0F0"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.107"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.01" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/searchbutton"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:contentDescription="@string/activities"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.154"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/activity"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.01" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/saves"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:contentDescription="@string/activities"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_saves"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.242"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/searchbutton"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.01" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:contentDescription="@string/activities"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_setting"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.673"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/saves"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.01" />




    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/mainList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#F0F2F5"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try it **recycler.scrollToPosition(0)**?

Comment: Just comes up as red and not actionable

Comment: Why do you call Intent to scroll? New activity  can't see your recycler.

Comment: New activity refreshes content, but instead of refreshing I just want to go to the top

Comment: Could you show more code?

Comment: added for clarity

Comment: I've made some example for you in my [git](https://github.com/Gizcerbes/androidJun/tree/Recycler)

Comment: I'm not sure.. set recyclerview height 0dp and try scrollToPosition

Comment: How are you actually accessing that `RecyclerView`? Because you're calling `smoothScrollTo` on `mRecyclerView` which isn't defined anywhere in your code. And your reply to Andrei's suggestion saying it "comes up red" makes me wonder if you copied some code and don't know how to adapt it to your own. Does `val mRecyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.mainList)` on the line before `mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0)` help? Does your app actually run?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for going to the top of the recyclerView.

```
mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

or

```
mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
```

When your list changes in recyclerView adapter, you should use that code. Make sure other parts of the code. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Using a comments answer from @cactustictacs, I edited my code to this and it worked:

```
val activity: ImageButton =findViewById(R.id.activity)
        val mRecyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.mainList)
        activity.setOnClickListener{
            mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0)
        }
```